# displaying 'category' of post in header tag

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress posts have categories (done through the admin panel) I want I have the post showing and want my h2 title to show the category. I can only find the `<h2><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>`function when i research which isn't working.

html

```
<?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>

<h2>  category name </h2>

<p> .......  </p>
```

Comment: the question is:- how's you are getting your posts? Please show that code. current code have nothing

Comment: is the lack of echo before the single_cat_title() a typo or is that intentional?

Comment: @CMiller - That function echoes the title by default so unless you pass `false` as the second argument, you don't need to echo it yourself.

Comment: OIC! No super familiar with WP.

Comment: Can you tell me in which page you wish to show the category title? like in single post page or category archive page?

Comment: Trying to put the title in the index.php. And the lack of echo infront of single_cat is intentional as I don't think that code would work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question but [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)  works outside the loop (loop see bottom) and I use it in a plugin.

It returns an array of category related elements for the current (by default) post.

Possible code for your usecase (not tested)

1. If your posts are only ever associated with one category and code is in post template (depends on theme):

   ```
   <?php 
   the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
   $categories = get_the_category();
   if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
     echo '<h2>' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</h2>';   
   }
   ?>
   <p> .......  </p>
   ```
2. if code is in header.php then likely and you only want your `<h2>` applied to posts:

   ```
   if (! is_front_page() && ! ..... ) { above code}
   ```
3. posts can be associated with multiple categories in which case you may need to `foreach` the $categories for name and concatenate names, or determine which to use based on the category slug of the current post.

**Within "the loop":**

I'm not sure whether get_the_category() code above will work by default or whether post id is required as a parameter.  The [the_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) can ONLY be used in the loop - but this will give you an anchor link.